# How can I insert values into a table without specifying its attributes?

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I have function that queries into one of the tables in my database, and each time the query may be for a different table. I cannot seem to add data on a table without specifying the attribute.

I tried supplying the value directly without specifying the attribute in a mysql server and it did work. It just isn't working from my javascript.

```
connection.query(`INSERT INTO ${specificKindOfTable} VALUES ?`, 
[entriesForSpecificTable],function(err,result)
{
    if (err) throw err;
console.log("Inserted into specific kind of database as well");
})
```

EDIT: the error I got was a syntax error:

```
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1
```

Comment: Try removin the VALUES **`INSERT INTO ${specificKindOfTable}  ?`**

Comment: @nacho, I tried and it doesn't work

Comment: What do you have in [entriesForSpecificTable]??

Comment: @nacho i have an entriesForSpecifcTable has an array, each member of which is also an array having in sequential order the values that i want to insert

Answer (score 0):

You can use the syntax (example):

```
INSERT INTO ${specificKindOfTable} VALUES ('a', 1, ...)
```

which does not mention the columns, if and only if you enter values for ALL the columns in the order they appear on the table.

Comment: is there anyway I can pass the values as an array? Because if the attributes of a table are variable, then so are the values, no?

Comment: @aapap looks like you're doing the right thing cause you can pass an array as variable, how does `[entriesForSpecificTable]` look like?

Comment: i have an entriesForSpecifcTable has an array, each member of which is also an array having in sequential order the values that i want to insert

Comment: @aapap sounds like you want to insert multiple lines at once, this doesn't work. Try a single record.